# How initiate the server inside gitlab-runner?

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, gitlab-ci, supertest

I have my tests in TS with jest and supertest. Locally all works but inside the gitlab-runner (gitlab-ci) all falied because this:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'address' of undefined
```

This error is because don't find the server, but is there o_O

Only inside the runner apper this error.

An example of test:

```
beforeAll(async () => {
    app = await Server.init();
});

afterAll(async () => {
    await app.close();
});

test('it should return 200', async () => {
     const res = await request(app).post(`${URL}/ok`).send(body);
     expect(res.status).toEqual(200);
});
```

I'm export my listen server in the application. This tests is inside a describe.

Thanks